# Problem sending analog read values over serial

Tags: raspbian, python, serial, arduino

Ok I apologize as I have edited this quite a bit, but I have narrowed down the problem a bit more. For some reason I can't transfer values from my arduino analog pins??

I am trying to send values from my arduino to raspberry pi over serial (USB cable).

Here is very simple code:

```
int someVal = 0;
int inputPinA = A0;
int pin = 0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
someVal++;
Serial.println(someVal);
delay(100);
pin = analogRead(inputPinA);
Serial.println(pin);
}
```

When my arduino is plugged into my windows PC, running the arduino IDE, this prints exactly as expected.
When my arduino is plugged into my raspberry pi, `someval` is printed normal, but `pin` is just 0 repeating... 
I tried changing `int pin = 1;` at the beginning to see if it would print 1 instead of 0, but nothing. I also tried `Serial.println(String(pin));` which still printed 0.... what is going on here, I am stumped.

Raspberry pi code:

```
import serial 

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600,8,'N',1,timeout=None)
ser_bytes = 0
decoded_bytes = 0


while True:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    recoatVal = str(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
    print(recoatVal)
```

I also simplified my python code to:

```
import serial 

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600,8,'N',1,timeout=None)
ser_bytes = 0

while True:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    print(ser_bytes)
```

Which just returns(prints):

`b '1\r\n'` <----someVal

`b '0\r\n'`<----pin

Also, some people were asking for what the arduino outputs:

```
1
245
2
556
3
433
4
545
...and so on
```

Comment: upvote for thinking about where to post your question and for not posting at multiple places

Comment: @MattG, Ah let me see. (1) Rpi USB UART/serial program can send something to Arduino which prints it in its own Arduino terminal. (2) Arduino can send something serial to Rpi, which receives it , and then sends that something back to Arduino which receives it and prints it in its Arduino terminal. (3) Now the TROUBLE: This time Arduino first does some averaging thing and then sends the averaged result to Rpi, But this time Rpi does not receive anything. Why?  Do I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: I edited question with hopes of the problem being more clear

Comment: You should include in you question **what the Arduino outputs**.  The construct `str(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))` looks bizarre, and is probably obscuring whatever is input. This looks more like a python coding question rather than a Pi question.

Comment: Ok I figured it out... but need someone to actually explain it, as I don't think this counts as an answer.
If I change `int pin = 0` to `float pin = 0` it works.... no idea why

Comment: @MattG If you have a new question please either edit your question to ask it or ask another question.  However this seem to be an Arduino question as the error was in the Arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

MattG,

`analogRead` a returns a float.. and the `print()` was probably getting confused too.

Leave out the `int inputPinA = A0;` because you only need to put A0 in the AnalogRead.

Make `int pin = 0;` a float, or better use `float pin_value = 0.0;` for clarity

Then the stuff in your loop becomes:

```
pin_value = analogRead(A0); Serial.println(pin_value);
```

Dave

Comment: I don't understand this answer. First, analogRead returns an integer, not a float. And second, what's confusing about printing a float?